# Liquibase 4.0 fails to start in jar

Tags: spring-boot, jar, liquibase, java-11

I use Spring 2.3.3 and Liquibase 4.0.0.
It works fine when run gradlew bootRun, but when I run compiled jar I get plenty of messages like:

```
    2020-09-11 17:40:33.267  WARN 1 --- [           main] liquibase.integration                    : Cannot create filesystem for url jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-aspects-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/: null

java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: null

...

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfigurati
on.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: Error parsing classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
```

Liqubase gradle config and runtime libraries:

```
configurations {
liquibaseRuntime.extendsFrom runtime

compileOnly {
    extendsFrom annotationProcessor
}

Properties liquibaseProps = new Properties()
liquibaseProps.load(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/liquibase.properties"))

Properties applicationProps = new Properties()
applicationProps.load(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/application.properties"))

liquibase {

    activities {

        main {
            referenceUrl 'hibernate:spring:' + liquibaseProps.getProperty('liquibase.domain.package') + '?dialect=' + applicationProps.getProperty('spring.jpa.database-platform') + '&hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy'
            driver applicationProps.getProperty('spring.datasource.driver-class-name')
            changeLogFile liquibaseProps.getProperty('liquibase.changelog.path') + migrationName() + '.yaml'
            url applicationProps.getProperty('spring.datasource.url')
            username applicationProps.getProperty('spring.datasource.username')
            password applicationProps.getProperty('spring.datasource.password')
        }
    }
}
}
```

Runtime:

```
liquibaseRuntime 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.0.0'
liquibaseRuntime 'org.liquibase:liquibase-groovy-dsl:2.1.2'
liquibaseRuntime 'org.postgresql:postgresql'

liquibaseRuntime 'org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate5:4.0.0'
liquibaseRuntime sourceSets.main.output

liquibaseRuntime "ch.qos.logback:logback-core"
liquibaseRuntime "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic"
liquibaseRuntime 'org.yaml:snakeyaml'
liquibaseRuntime group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.1'

liquibaseRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
liquibaseRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
liquibaseRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
```

**liquibase.properties:**

```
liquibase.changelog.path="classpath:src/main/resources/db/changelog/changes/"
liquibase.domain.package=ru.example.entities
```

Application configuration
**application.properties**

```
spring.application.name = "Example"
application.description = "Example"
application.version = 1.0


spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy = org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql:localhost:5432/test
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=qwerty
```

How can I fix it?

**Update:**

Updated *resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml*:

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - includeAll:
      path: classpath:db/changelog/changes/
```

Updated liquibase config in gradle:

```
    liquibase {
        activities {
            main {
                classpath "$projectDir/src/main/resources/db/changelog"
...
```

Added to *application.properties:*
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml

Now I still get a warnings about not found jar dependencies:

```
liquibase.integration                    : Cannot create filesystem for url jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-aspects-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/: null

java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: null
        at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:172) ~[jdk.zipfs:na]
```

And still not found embedded changeset:

```
 Could not find directory or directory was empty for includeAll 'db/changelog/changes/'
```

Problem with includeAll fixes if replace it with explicit declaration:

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - include:
      file: changes/20200829022849_default.yaml
      relativeToChangelogFile: true
```

**Update 2**
Here is a link on repository https://github.com/dekar91/liquibase_ex
I build and start application like so:

```
./gradleew bootJar
java -jar example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: provide your config of liquibase in spring .

Comment: @bilak ok, added.

Comment: show what you have inside applicaiton.properties please

Comment: Added application and liqubase properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a commited *liquibase 4.0.0 issue* https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/1276
Liuquibase **3.10.2** works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

From your configuration it looks like liquibase is potinting to it's default which is `classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml`.

So add to your `application.properties` property:

`spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/changelog/changes/<filename>` - note add there also file name so it colud pick the main changelog.

Comment: Is not the same as liquibase.changelog.path from liquibase.properties?
Checked. Stll warnings like "liquibase.integration                    : Cannot create filesystem for url jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-aspects-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/: null
java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: null"
I checked if these jar exists inside /lib. It does. Propable it is conencted with docker or windows hosts?

Comment: well try to provide example on github so we can help you. but if there is an exception `null java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: null` you probably configured something wrong.

Comment: Added to description.